I how do you get the value out of this Json with PHP
    {
      "totalSize":1,
      "done":true,
      "records":[
        {
          "attributes": 
            { 
              "type":"Order",
              "url":"/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/Order/801bb00000CsZGQAA3"
            },
            "Id":"801bb00000CsZGQAA3"
        }]
    }

I am trying to get the Id. I am assigning the json decode as $data2
I have tried
$data2['records']['attributes']['Id'] 
$data2['records']['Id']
$data2->records->Id

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Records is an array of objects, so $data2['records'][0]...

@aynber so I should use $data2['records'][1]?

Only if there's multiple records. PHP starts with a 0 index. If you need the ID for multiple records, then I would suggest iterating through $data2['records'] with a foreach

oh ok, so the "attributes" isn't a record, the Id is the 1st record. Got it, let me give that a try.

So $data2['records'][0] resluts in an array. I was trying to not do a loop because I only need the ID, but if I need to I can do a loop. I was hoping for a way to pull the ID with no loop.

Well, if I'm not mistaken, the value in the totalSize field would give you a clue if you need to loop or not, for any given record. If you know you only ever want the item from the first entry in the array, then just use $data2['records'][0]["attributes"["Id"] to get it directly.

Yes, $data2['records'][0] is an array, which is why I put the ellipsis. $data2['records'][0] has two array keys, attributes, and Id. ADyson has a bit of a typo, to get the Id, you'd use $data2['records'][0]['Id']

Sorry yes, anyber is correct, I misread it. $data2['records'][0]['Id'] is what you'd need, to get the Id from the first record in the array.
